# Cordova App 8.1 Caching HTTP request

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cordova, caching, visual-studio-cordova

I'm working on an app using Visual Studio 2015 Cordova tools on Windows 8.1. Target is also Windows 8.1.

The app is caching HTTP GET request. So the second GET request to the same resource returns a cached response. I have tested after disabling the network adapter and I still get a response with the cached results.

I am using jsforce libray to connect to salesforce.com. I know I can add a timestamp on the url but I would like to find fix not a work around.

Any ideas?

[UPDATE]

Issue is not related to jsforce as it works well on Android. The error is specific to Windows 8.1 and cordova.

Comment: I can confirm this weird issue, looking forward for suggestions.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: No, still using timestamp

Comment: did u found any solution.. ? I'm stuck in the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

As suggested in the question, timestamping the url helps: I used:

```
var url = "https://api.myurl.com/" + param1 + "?" + new Date().getTime()
```

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a simple library to add caching to REST requests for Cordova: https://github.com/glauber-md/mobile-simple-web-call#using-this-library .

The library will use a local database (sqlite) to fetch server data and cache it locally where applicable (e.g. HTTP GET requests with cache-related headers).

Once it receives a 304 Response, it will use the cached data.

To send a GET request, you'd use:

```
wscall.get(
    'http://myserver.org/users/1234',
    // (Optional) query strings
    null,
    function(responseData) {
        // Do something when the response is successful
    },
    function(error) {
        // Do something when an error happens
    }
);
```

Then the data would come from remote server or local cache depending of the HTTP server response.

Maybe it will help you.